# How to specify Google Chrome default pdf viewer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Using Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have [xodo](https://www.xodo.com/app/) installed as a browser app for viewing pdf files.

I want to keep the app, but don't want it as the *default* pdf viewer (ie. when looking at some pdf for the first time on a website in chrome, I want to use the default pdf viewer).

However, I cannot find how to change it going to `settings -> advanced -> privacy and security -> content -> pdf documents` only gives the option to choose whether to download file rather than opening in Chrome.

Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: [Here's what you're looking for](https://askubuntu.com/a/61647/761963)